# How do I pass data into a click() function when manually call it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons: `#btn1` and `#btn2`. I have set up the following click event handlers:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(event){
   // do something...
})

$('#btn2').click(function(event){
  $('#btn1').click(); // works
  $('#btn1').click({data:5}); // not firing at all
})
```

I have Googled but most of the posts are talking about how to display the data when a user really clicks. However, in my case, I am not clicking the `#btn1` but just call the `click()` handler from another function.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$( "#btn1" ).data( "data", 5 );` <-- you can use `data-attribute` and in the event extract it (but seems doesn't have so much sense)

Comment: If I need to pass very complicated data, this is not a good way, I have to `JSON.stringify` the data. So this is the only way?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.trigger()`:

```js
$('#btn1').trigger('click', { data: 5 });
```

and then the handler should look like:

```js
$('#btn1').click((event, data) => {
  // data should be { data: 5 } here
})
```

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

https://jsfiddle.net/hrcnskzm/